# Understand the call function in R

Tags: r

I copied the function from the web:

```
# function used to predict Best Subset Selection Regression
predict.regsubsets = function(object, newdata, id, ...) {
    form = as.formula(object$call[[2]])
    mat = model.matrix(form, newdata)
    coefi = coef(object, id = id)
    mat[, names(coefi)] %*% coefi
}
```

However, when I try to use the above function within another function , I kept getting the following error.

```
library(leaps)    
abc <- function(){
        regfit <- regsubsets(lpsa ~.,data = XTraining, nvmax = 8)
        predict.regsubsets(regfit, data = XTesting, id = 1)
    }
    abc()
    Error in object$call[[2]] : subscript out of bounds
```

I read `?call` in R already. But it doesn't help me understanding what went wrong here, in particular what is `$call[[2]]` ?

How can I edit the function above such that when I call the above function inside another function I won't get an error ?

Comment: I believe that object is a `fit` object which is returned by `lm` like functions. `object$call[[2]]` returns the formula used in `lm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is the line

```
form = as.formula(object$call[[2]])
```

This implies that `object` (which is the variable you pass to the function, in your example `regfit`) has a member called `call`, which is a list with at least two elements. `[[ ]]` is the R operator used to take the elements of a list.

For instance:

```
> a <- list(1:10, 1:5, letters[15:20])

> a[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> a[[3]]
[1] "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t"
```

However

```
> a[[5]] # This does not work, as a only has three elements
Error in a[[5]] : subscript out of bounds
```

You should not check `?call` but rather the help for the function that generates `object`, in your case `regsubsets`.

As you can see from `?regsubsets`, or by using `str(regfit)`, that function does not return an object with a member named `call`.

To get the formula from a `regsubsets` object you need to look at the `obj` member of the summary.

For instance you could use:

```
sm <- summary(regfit)
sm$obj$call
```

Comment: So how can I extract the formula from `regfit` within a function ?

Comment: @Chinegro: updated my answer. Looks a tad involved, but if there is a more direct method I could not find it.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is in the function `abc`. The argument in the `predict.regsubsets` is called `newdata`, but you refer to is as `data`....

Answer (score 0):

The `object` is probably the output from a previous analysis (look at the place you got the code from what function). The line `form = as.formula(objects$call[[2]])` extracts the  formula used to create the  object and stores it in `form`. In the next lines it is used to create the model matrix of the new data, and finally uses it to predict the new data.

Comment: hi, I have given a full code to illustrate the problem. Please see it.